# Creating a clean root filesystem (with overlay) without rebuilding all the packages

Tags: buildroot

I currently have a buildroot configuration that outputs a U-Boot-wrapped root filesystem. Part of that process overlays files from a outside directory, which contains things like network interfaces, profile.d scripts, and some custom executables.

My question is this: what is the best way to recreate the root filesystem image, without rebuilding all the extra packages? Just deleting the output/images and output/target directories, followed by a "make all" doesn't seem to work. For the most common usage, I don't need to rebuild the toolchain, or any other packages. I just need the root filesystem recreated, with the overlay performed. However, there doesn't seem to be a good make target to do a clean on the output only, or a build of the target filesystem/images.

Thanks,

-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you invoke "make", the root filesystem image is completely re-created from the contents of output/target/, the post-build scripts are executed and the rootfs overlays are copied.

So if you make a change to a rootfs overlay, a change to a post-build script, or you add/remove stuff from output/target/, simply running "make" is sufficient.

However, if your aim is to remove output/target/ completely with the hope that it will reinstall all packages, then indeed this doesn't work, and we have good reasons for not supporting this, because there are many situations where this can give an incorrect result.